# How to set fake GPS location in Appium

Tags: selenium, automation, appium

I saw that there is the method to set the Location `driver.setLocation(Location);`
But which driver do I need for this? 
And is this usable for Android and iOS?

Comment: https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/geolocation/set-geolocation/

Answer (score 2):

For emulators or simulators, which are the easiest to configure, use the following capabilities.

**Android**

```
gpsEnabled: true
```

**iOS**

```
locationServicesEnabled: true
locationServicesAuthorized: true
```

It is required to provide the `bundleId` capability for the latter to work.

For real devices, things are more tricky. In Android you should be able to enable mock locations in the Developer Settings, however, I haven't been able to put it to work using Appium `setLocation` method. This question invoking Appium settings app through adb might help you in that regard: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35716/is-it-possible-to-set-devices-latitude-and-longitude-using-adb-shell.

Finally, for iOS, you can use a run configuration with a fake location from XCode, but I haven't found any method to programatically run the app with a fake location from an Appium automation.